# Bind to a method not directly in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I want to bind a method from one of my classes to a button in my UI.

I currently have a working version of it but I don't like it because I just want to save on code and I would really love to call the method directly...

**Page.xaml**

```
<Button Content="Request Data" 
        FontSize="20" 
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Margin="0 20 0 0" 
        Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.RequestData}" />  //this is how I call it at the moment

<Button Content="Request Data" 
        FontSize="20" 
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Margin="0 20 0 0" 
        Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DataBlock.RequestData}" /> //this is how I tried to call it (which seems totally fine to me)
        //Error i get is "RequestData is not a method"
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
}

public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

**ViewModel** (just the used code for this case)

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Data DataBlock = new Data();

    public async void RequestData()
    {
         await DataBlock.RequestData();
    }
}
```

**DataBlock**

```
public class Data
{
    public async Task RequestData
    {
         //Method here
    }
}
```

I just shortened the code to the most significant bits. There are more methods like this...And I would really love to just call them directly instead of calling them with yet another method :/

When I try to bind it directly it tells me that it is not a method.

I would really appreciate a little help here :)

Comment: "it tells me that it is not a method" : always include exact error messages.

Comment: It just tells me "RequestData is not a method"

Comment: Post the _exact_ definition of RequestData , and the _exact_ call.

Comment: `ViewModel` is just a name. Binding targets the *context* of a control, window, container. Your statement says `bind to the RequestData method of the property named ViewModel in the current context`. Where is the context set? What is the type and value of the `ViewModel` property there?

Comment: Yes, do post the _exact_ definition of your ViewModel property as well.

Comment: Right, your code is complete now. I think you'll have to stick to the ViewModel intermediary because of the `async Task` / `async void` issues alone. I wouldn't know how to `await` in XAML.

Comment: I also tested this with a simple `public void Test()` method without any async stuff and I get the same error. So it's a general thing not only with the async stuff. And the mothod I call in the ViewModel is also `async` so it would actually need an `await` too

Comment: Doesn't work because RequestData is a Task, and the x:Bind compiler won't bind to a Task as a method. Make it a synchronous method like your intermediary async void method and all is good.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake as I said 2 comments before i tried it with a `public void Test()` method and got the same error. No Task there...

Comment: @Daniel Did you ever get rid of the error? I get the same error despite the code running fine.

Comment: @geometrikal I do think that I got rid of the error somehow... But I haven't worked with UWP for a year so I can't really say how unfortunately :/